# Replace selectedText with Task output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a task which passes highlighted text (${selectedText}) to an external script and the output gets printed in the terminal.

Is there anyway to have that script output replace the highlighted text?

:)

Even saving to a new file and merging into the existing file would be fine, that seems far more complicated though.

Answer (score 1):

I found I can do this in a slightly more round about way than I intended. VSCode Tasks can be shell operations, so I solved the problem using bash shell tools like sed and awk.

1.) Have the output of my script get saved to a temporary file.

2.) Using sed -i I can strategically erase the highlighted lines (after determining the range of lines highlighted).

3.) Then using AWK I can paste the temp file output into specific lines in my primary file. I could do it all in sed or awk but found it easier to use both.

4.) Clean up by deleting the temp file.

So there is no all in one nice VSCode solution that I could find, but it is doable.